# how to use two onChangeText in react native inside textinput

Tags: react-native, textinput

```
<TextInput          
 placeholder="Full Name"
 onChangeText={userName => this.setState({ userName })} 
 onChangeText={text => this.validate(text, "username")}  
 underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 style={[
         styles.TextInputStyleClass,
         !this.state.nameValidate ? styles.error : null
       ]}
 blurOnSubmit={false}
 autoFocus={true}
 autoCorrect={true}
 autoCapitalize="none"
 maxLength={25}
/>
```

in the above code, I use two Onchagnetext events but only on event work that calls validation another is not working means not take value. why how to fix it.
how can I use two Onchangetext events?

Comment: Do you want both of them work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two `onChangeText` method.

If you want to validate and use setState together then you can do

```
   ...
   onChangeText={userName => this.setState({ userName },
    () => this.validate(username, 'username)})}
```

The **callback** in `setState` ensures that you are calling the method once the `setState` has finished updating the `state`